# Provision failed in android using ESP provisioning Library

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Hi in the below code provision result I am getting provision failed but device changing from provisioning to data mode.

```
   try {
  wifiAccesspointName = Constant.SSID;
  wifiAccesspointPassword = Constant.PASS_PHASE;
  new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> {
  pesManager.connectToDevice(result.getDevice(), wifiAccesspointName, wifiAccesspointPassword);
              
                                  }, 60000);
```

PesManager.java:

```
public void connectToDevice(BluetoothDevice device, String wifiAccesspointName, String wifiAccesspointPassword) {

        provisionManager.getEspDevice().provision(wifiAccesspointName, wifiAccesspointPassword, this );

    }
```